# Including an external library to my own library project c++ visual studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, linker, dependencies, static-libraries

Currently i have 3 visual studio projects:

- ConsoleApplication
- Logic
- Test

These projects are all in the same solution. In the Logic project i use an external library named curl. My logic project is a static library made with the "new project" wizard in visual studio. This project includes a pch.h file. I added following things to my Logic project properties:

1. Set `C/C++ > General > Additional Include Directories` to the folder with the header files of curl
2. Set `Libarian > General > Additional Library Directories` to the folder with curl.lib in it.
3. Set `Libarian > General > Additional Dependencies` to curl.lib.

Now when i build the Logic project the output is a Logic.lib file. i checked with DUMPBIN  /SYMBOLS /EXPORTS Logic.lib if the Curl functions are actually in the lib file, and they are.

To include the Logic project into the Console application i did the same 3 steps and added the Logic.lib to the Console application project. Everything works fine untill the moment i start using classes that use the external curl library. When i use these classes i get a link error: Unresolved external symbol (LNK 2019). I have tried much to fix this, but it seems that i am not capable of solving it. Am i doing something wrong that causes this not to work?

Also i would like to be able to use my logic project the same way as i do in my ConsoleApplication in my test project. For more context why i splitted up those projects can be found in my previous question [Use c++ classes from console application class in other project visual studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64537645/use-c-classes-from-console-application-class-in-other-project-visual-studio)

Comment: I expect you somehow messed up the settings and didn't properly link to curl.lib in the project that you see errors. Make sure you add the settings for all configurations.

Comment: Yes i pointed to the correct lib file for all the four configurations even for x64 or x86. And when i run my console application in debug or release in x86 or x64 it all generates the same error. I also tested the lib files in a console application without a library project and that just works

Comment: You added curl.lib for your console application? Adding logic.lib is not sufficient.

Comment: There is a setting that can make this work: [https://stackoverflow.com/a/61689250/487892](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61689250/487892)

Comment: I haved added curl.lib to my console application. It works when i call curl directly from console application. but when i use the class from my library that uses curl  i get the same error. When i use both my class and directly use curl it suddenly works. But i get a warning (LNK4217)

Comment: Is Logic.lib a dll? I expected it was a static library. The `LNK4217` is about dlls

Comment: No in the configuration it says Static library (.lib)

Comment: The LNK4217 is about dllimport / dllexport which is confusing. You should not use that with a static lib

Comment: I assume curl is a dll and your are linking the import library for curl.

Comment: Maybe it's because i had to add several dlls to Additional dependecies because curl needed them: ws2_32.lib;wldap32.lib;advapi32.lib;kernel32.lib;comdlg32.lib;crypt32.lib;normaliz.lib;

Comment: No i have build the static library versions of curl. i followed this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q_mXVZ6VJs4&t=448s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after hours of research i found this post and i think this also applies to my case: [Linking static libraries to other static libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2157629/linking-static-libraries-to-other-static-libraries)

TL;DR static libraries do not link with other static libraries

So i think the best solution in my case is to convert the static logic library to a dynamic lib (DLL)

Comment: This used to be the case but I believe this answer fixes this: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61689155/how-to-combine-two-static-libraries/61689250#61689250](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61689155/how-to-combine-two-static-libraries/61689250#61689250) however for my projects I have never tried this. I always specify all the libraries I need.

Comment: I tried to change that option in the property window of my Logic project but I still get the same error, maybe I have to try this with two static libraries that I created myself, because it might be a problem with the curl library specifically